# Lexicographically smallest perfect matching

Tags: algorithm, matching

I want to find the lexicographically smallest perfect matching in two partial graphs. I'm supposed to use Kuhn's algorithm, but I don't understand how to make matching lexicographically smallest. Is it at all possible in Kuhn's algorithm? I can provide my code, but it's classic enough.

Comment: @Benjamin, it's almost the same but for weighted matching. Do you know how to find _lexicographically smallest_ matching using it and can you give me proof?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://books.google.ca/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&lpg=PA668&ots=BxNoBH-nB8&dq=lexicographically%20smallest%20matching&pg=PA664#v=onepage&q=lexicographically%20smallest%20matching&f=false There is also good information in the Wikipedia links, such as http://www.cse.ust.hk/~golin/COMP572/Notes/Matching.pdf

Comment: As far as I know it's given as exercise in Cormen.

Comment: So the proof is what your after? You might want to head over to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, consider how you could determine where just the first node should be matched in the lex-min matching.

Comment: Yep, currently I use such an implementation, which is n^2 time worse than Kuhn's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases like this it is usually easier to make a reduction instead of modifying the algorithm:

- Find a way to change the input in your problem so that lexicographical order breaks any ties (but in a manner that perfect matchings still have a higher score than imperfect ones)
- Run the modified graph through Kuhn's algorithm.
- If needed, translate the answer back to the original problem.

---

I haven't tried to actually solve this myself or read the problem in detail. But this seems to be a textbook exercise and I feel this answer is enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you can create assignment prices that encourage lexicographically early matchings.